# Linux USB: libusb vs sysfs

Tags: usb, sysfs

On a Linux system, I need to list all USB hosts and devices with various information like class, product id, etc. I figure both libusb and sysfs are up to the task (correct?). So which one is the better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer libusb because it is platform independent and provides better APIs to work with USB devices than sysfs.

If you do not need to integrate this functionality in some other program, consider using the standalone `usb-devices` or even `lsusb` programs (which are included with the `usbutils` package).